# Quickblox: What's the strategy for making Video call to offline user

Tags: android, video, push-notification, quickblox

I am making an android app that does video calling. Currently Quickblox allows you to make video call only when the receiver is online. In android when the screen is off and the phone is trying to conserve power the app has to logout from chat and the user becomes offline. This is a very common situation and I can not make video call to the offline user anymore.

How do I solve this very common problem. One way to maybe solve this problem is to send the receiver a push message and then the app can wake up and login to chat. This approach is not good since push notifications are not reliable and may take a long time.

Is there any other way to solve this problem? Another similar problem is that when a user is not running the app, how can I make a video call to the user?

Answer (score 0):

that's an interesting question, but as far as I know the approach you described (using offline push notifications) is the only technically possible one.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I solve this very common problem. One way to maybe solve this
>   problem is to send the receiver a push message and then the app can
>   wake up and login to chat. This approach is not good since push
>   notifications are not reliable and may take a long time.

This is the right way to do it here.

Other way is to wrap QuickBlox Chat into Android Services and have a persistent connection with chat. So you will be online while you have an active internet connection.

So you can choose one solution and go with it

Comment: Using push messages is not a good option for a commercial video app comparable to Skype. I am trying to run Quickblox chat as a permanent Service in the background but one problem is that the presence messages puts a drain on the battery when the Android device is sleeping. Is there a way to turn off presence messages while logged onto chat. I am using QBRoster.

Comment: @user2994098 It is possible with Android SDK 2.3 via mobile optimisations http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Mobile_optimisations